# different numFound from solr api and solr dashboard for same solr query

Tags: solr

when fetch data from solr through solr api first time it gives wrong count in numFound where as again query with same gives right count in numFound.

solr query for both time was same.

Comment: q= userName:abhinash&sort=createDate+desc&start=0&rows=10

Comment: Are you running in a cluster setting? What is the difference in numbers? Do you get the correct answer if you run the API query twice (instead of through the dashboard the second time)? Are you sure both query methods are using the same `defType` / query parser?

Comment: @MatsLindh  (1) Are you running in a cluster setting = yes, (2) What is the difference in numbers? = get one doc less, (3) Do you get the correct answer if you run the API query twice (instead of through the dashboard the second time)? = yes, (4) Are you sure both query methods are using the same defType / query parser? = yes

Comment: Please update your _question_ with these points and relative examples. How many nodes? What does the log on each of the servers show for the query? Does the result set from one node possibly time out?